# Any way to increase the size of the Android System log file?

Tags: android, file, size, system, logging

Any way to increase the size of the Android System log file?

I'm on Gingerbread

Only get like an hour of data.. I'd like to see a full day.  I'm using Sendlog app to send me the log.

Comment: Here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56730011/1084174

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that is possible to increase the buffer size of the adb logcat log, but when I need log for the whole day I do something like this

first connect the device with your pc and then
in shell I type

```
adb logcat > myWholeDayLogFile.txt
```

and the you can have the log from the whole day, when you open the file click reload friquently to reload the new changes

Answer (score 2):

Connect to your device using:

```
adb shell
```

Then increase the buffer size via:

```
logcat -r <nrKB> -f <logFileName> &
```

The ampersand will let it run in background so you can quit the adb shell and disconnect your PC. Log buffer size should return to normal once you reboot your phone.

See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Answer (score 0):

"adb logcat -g" will show the current buffer sizes.
"adb logcat -G <size>K/M" will set the current buffer sizes.

For example, setting the buffer sizes to 1024Kb:
"adb logcat -G 1024K"