# How to change size of logcat buffer in Android?

Tags: android

I noticed that the size of the logcat buffer varies on different devices. Assuming I have root permissions on my device, is there a way to change the buffer size of the main buffer at runtime? If not, then assuming I can rebuild the Android image, how do I change it at compile time? I'm looking to enlarge it for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: Nice doc is in http://elinux.org/Android_logger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the newsgroup *Android Developers*, *[logcat buffer size](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/fsMZFz9IoNo)*:

> The log buffers on the device are 64 KB. The timestamp, process ID,
>   and log level are stored in a compact format, so you may actually get
>   more than 64 KB of formatted data out of `logcat -d -v <mode>`.

Comment: Should the buffer size be updated? I got 256Kb when I ran `adb logcat -g` to check the buffer information.

Comment: @Cosmoandcat that number was accurate in Android 2.4 and lower. You are likely on Android 4.x. The size increased in 3.0. Nature of updates.

Comment: See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56730011/1084174 if you want to set size for specific buffer type

Answer (score 25):

###See current buffer size

```bash
adb logcat -g
```

###Set all type buffer size (main, system, crash)

```bash
adb logcat -G 16M # 16M can be replace by (128K ~ 16M)
```

###Set specific type buffer size (main, system, crash)

```bash
adb logcat -b system -G 8M # system can be replaced with 'main' or 'crash'
```

Comment: I just tried `-G 20M` and it seems to apply as well..?

Comment: @YoavFeuerstein some manufacturers/os might override that standards so there can be exceptions.

Comment: thanks for the warning! Do you know of any specific examples and how it affects this command?

Comment: Your case is the example of such deviation

Comment: oh right, I thought you meant something else :) Thanks!

Comment: I've noticed that when I use `adb logcat -G` to change the buffer size that it does not retain the change on a reboot of the device, and the Developer Options screen continues to display the old setting. Any idea why?

Comment: Found my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57657874/137646. The boot option is based on the property `persist.logd.size`.

Answer (score 23):

**"Logger buffer size option" in "Developer options"**

It allows to change the size to a few values between 64k and 16M.

`adb logcat -g` then immediately shows the update limit.

Tested on 5.1.1, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32094784/895245) claims that it is a recent addition.

Answer (score 17):

Set the size of the log ring buffer

```
adb logcat -G <size>
```

Append K or M to indicate kilobytes or megabytes

Example: `adb logcat -G 512K`

Answer (score 3):

No, as per [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/fsMZFz9IoNo) it seems that the log buffers on the device are 64 KB. The timestamp, process ID, and log level are stored in a compact format, so you may actually get more than 64 KB of formatted data out of `logcat -d -v <mode>`.

See also Stack Overflow question *[What is the size limit for Logcat?](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)*.

Anyway, for saving logs elsewhere, you have *[Reading and Writing Logs](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)*. That maybe could help you.

Answer (score 3):

The buffer size is determined by the kernel, found in */drivers/staging/android/logger.c.

Which buffers are used and the size has changed with Android versions. [Android 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_3.0_Honeycomb_.28API_level_11.29) (Honeycomb) and newer also have a system buffer, and all four are 256 KB. You have to recompile the kernel to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the value of idea.cycle.buffer.size=1024 in property file android-studio\bin\idea.properties. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To set logcat buffer to 16Mb for a specific Android device through adb, I used:

`adb -s 2615a1d4e3174a6e logcat -G 16M`

But you can use just:

`adb logcat -G 16M`

Or set previous buffer size with:

`adb logcat -G 256K`