# adb logcat - missing logs

Tags: android, logging, adb, android-logcat

I am fairly new to Android and I want to understand the activity lifecycle. The documentation on the Android developer site is really great for that, but I want to see the lifecycle in action.

So, I create a new simple project and in the main activity, I overwrite the methods `onCreate()`, `onDestroy()`, `onStart()`, `onStop()`, `onResume()` and `onPause()` and add a log statement to each of it.

Then, I fire up the simulator and open the app, change orientation, switch to another app and so on and have a look on the log statements to see what's going on.

I notice strange behaviours. For example: I start the app for the very first time:

```
02-21 10:22:32.470 I/MainActivity( 2114): onCreate called.
02-21 10:22:32.520 I/MainActivity( 2114): onStart called.
02-21 10:22:32.520 I/MainActivity( 2114): onResume called.
```

That's what I expected, fine.
Then, I open the *recents apps* switcher.

```
02-21 10:24:01.520 I/MainActivity( 2114): onPause called.
02-21 10:24:01.520 I/MainActivity( 2114): onStop called.
```

I switch back to it:

```
02-21 10:24:26.050 I/MainActivity( 2114): onStart called.
02-21 10:24:26.050 I/MainActivity( 2114): onResume called.
```

So far, so good. Then, I open the app switcher again:

```
02-21 10:24:31.670 I/MainActivity( 2114): onStop called.
```

Here it's getting weird. Where is `onPause()`? In my opinion, **this method has to be called** before `onStop()` is called.

These log messages are examples, sometimes the behaviour is slightly different and it is not always predictable. But always some log statements are missing.

I googled this and found something about "rotating" logs. My problem is: I do not understand why it is difficult to get all log statements. Period. Maybe there are some technical barriers, but from a developer point of view, while learning about a new ecosystem, this is just frustrating.

Am I missing something here? Is there a simple solution for getting all log entries?

Comment: Go there http://stackoverflow.com/a/9226244/1632286

Comment: @squiroid: The strange this is: the first time I open the _recent apps_ switcher, `onPause` is called. The second time, it is not.

Answer (score -1):

from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html:

> Tip: Don't forget that when you make a call like
>
> `Log.v(TAG, "index=" + i);`
>
> that when you're building the string to pass into Log.d, the compiler
>   uses a StringBuilder and at least three allocations occur: the
>   StringBuilder itself, the buffer, and the String object.
>   Realistically, there is also another buffer allocation and copy, and
>   even more pressure on the gc. That means that if your log message is
>   filtered out, you might be doing significant work and incurring
>   significant overhead.

From: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#filteringOutput

> Every Android log message has a tag and a priority associated with it.
>
> - The tag of a log message is a short string indicating the system component from which the message originates (for example, "View" for
>     the view system).
> - The priority is one of the following character values, ordered from lowest to highest priority:
>
>   - V — Verbose (lowest priority)
>   - D — Debug
>   - I — Info
>   - W — Warning
>   - E — Error
>   - F — Fatal
>   - S — Silent (highest priority, on which nothing is ever printed)

You may want to look into:

- [What is the size limit for Logcat and how to change its capacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6321555/1815624)
- [How to change size of logcat buffer in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12397780/1815624)